# How can I print this"█" special character in C++?

Tags: c++, special-characters

I want to print this special character █ in visual studio (c++) but I get "?" .
The corresponding code that I wrote:

```
bool b[5][3] = { { true,true,true },{ true,false,true },{ true,false,true }, 
                 { true,false,true },{ true,true,true } };
    system("color 0A");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (b[i][j])
            {
                gotoXY(3 + j, 5 + i);
                cout << "█";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Your editor will save that character to the source file as some series of bytes. The compiler will include those in the string literal and send them to the console. Will the console interpret the bytes correctly? Maybe. Using the `\u` escape helps on the source code side by ensuring a UTF-8 representation. Your console will have to be UTF-8 for it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use wide output:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main()
{
    ::_setmode(::_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    ::std::wcout << L"█" << ::std::flush;
    return 0;
}
```

Also if you are going to use pseudo graphics then you may want to select some pixel font for console so symbols will be rendered without antialiasing and gaps.

Comment: thank you very much by a little change worked.

#include<fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
::std::wcout << L"█" << ::std::flush;

Answer (score 2):

Try out: `std::cout <<"\u2588";`

█ unicode: [U+2588](https://unicode-table.com/en/2588/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. i tried it but did not work.

Comment: This only works is your console output supports it. So it's OS/ platform dependent.